# Remove Some Characters From URL Using 301 Redirect htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to remove some characters `?m=1` & `?m=0` from the end of my URLs. For this purpose I used a JavaScript from a blog post [**How To Forcefully Redirect Blogger Mobile Template To Desktop Template?**](http://www.exeideas.com/2014/07/redirect-blogger-mobile-to-desktop.html) and edit it with my desired till below one and its working fine.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var curl = window.location.href;if (curl.indexOf('m=1') != -1) {curl = curl.replace('m=1', '');window.location.href = curl;}
var curl = window.location.href;if (curl.indexOf('m=0') != -1) {curl = curl.replace('m=0', '');window.location.href = curl;}
</script>
```

Its removing my desired extra characters and then redirecting to the new URL but according to Google its not SE friendly and I have to use `301 Redirect` via `.htaccess` that will tell every search engine too that this URL is now change to this.

My URLs are showing as `http://www.blog.com/2014/08/post-title.html?m=1` & `http://www.blog.com/2014/08/post-title.html?m=0` now... So can I do the same using `.htaccess` and `301 Redirect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using mod_rewrite. You can check the query string in a condition with `%{QUERY_STRING}` and use the `[R=301]` flag to make it a permanent redirect. The `QSD` flag will discard the query string.

In Apache 2.4 and above you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=[01]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R,L]
```

In lower versions of Apache the QSD flag does not exist. You'll have to use a trick where you overwrite the query string by appending an empty query string to the rewrite target.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=[01]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
```

Change the `R` to `R=301` when the rule works as expected. Please note that you should place this **before** any other rule you have for your blog. There is most likely a catch-all rule in the end that sends the request to your blog backend, and you have to redirect before that happens.

Comment: After adding your code... Got `Internal Server Error` On Whole Site... :(

Comment: That's because I derped and forgot a `^` in the first argument. I have altered my answer.

Comment: Again After adding your code... Got `Internal Server Error` On Whole Site... :(

Comment: What's your Apache version?

Comment: I am on **Bluehost** and according to Wikipedia they are using `Apache HTTP Server version 2.2.26, and OpenSSL version 0.9.8e`.

Comment: You have an extra space after `^` that I removed and now its showing `404 Page` On my `?m=1` & `?m=0` URLs... `

Comment: I have rejected that edit, because it means something entirely different. `^` is a shorthand to match every url. `^http` matches no urls. The problem you have is that `QSD` has not been introduced until 2.4, which will cause an internal server error in earlier versions. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is what I want... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have this query string on your entire website, you can try this :

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^m=1$  [OR]
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^m=0$
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=301]
```

Comment: Added your code but nothing happen. Question is updated with my URLs current structure...

Comment: Other than the missing `L` flag this should work if you put it before other rules you already have.

Comment: Added it on the top of my `.htaccess` between `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>******</IfModule>` but still my URL is messed up with `?m=1` & `?m=0`...

Answer (score 0):

Here I got another solution for this so if upper isn't working for you then try this by adding below codes in top of `.htaccess` file...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=0$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$0? [R=301,L]
```

The above code will only work when your URL will be like `http://www.example.com?m=1` but not when `http://www.example.com?m=1&foo=bar`.